# Correct way of rails caching complex query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am new to caching and I'm not sure what my best course of action is.

I want to cache a part of my view that relies on a complex query. The query looks something like:

```
@sessions_next_week = group_by_wday(LittleClassSession.location_only([1,2]).age_range_only(age_from, age_to).supports_dropins_only(support).approved_users_only.next_week)
```

Above you'll see a number of scopes and methods called. The view renders an instance variable named `@sessions_next_week` like so:

```
<% @sessions_next_week.each do |wday, lcs| %>
  <h3><%= wday %></h3>
  <%= render partial: 'table_head' %>
  <% lcs.each do |s| %>
    <%= render partial: 'table_row', :locals => {:s => s, :show_day => true} %>
  <% end %>
  <%= render partial: 'table_foot' %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, `@sessions_next_week` is iterated through, and its children are iterated through. Given this, and given the nature of the query results in the instance variable, I'm not sure where to implement the caching. In the model? In the view?

So my questions are:

1. Do I need model caching or can I do this in the view?
2. What's the correct implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to simply add two character:

```
@sessions_next_week ||= group_by_wday(LittleClassSession.location_only([1,2]).age_range_only(age_from, age_to).supports_dropins_only(support).approved_users_only.next_week)
```

This is called memoization, and you can look it up. Here's one source: http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/

Comment: This is a good tip but I'm making several trips to the db with things like @sessions_next_week and I definitely need caching